# How to Schedule Laravel Queue Jobs on Shared Hosting Without Sudo Rights?

Tags: laravel, queue, scheduled-tasks, shared-hosting, job-scheduling

I'm a Laravel backend developer, and I have a scenario where I need to schedule queue jobs on shared hosting. These jobs involve sending emails to users when they register, and I'm currently using the php artisan queue:listen command to run them on my localhost. However, I'm facing challenges when it comes to running these jobs on shared hosting due to the lack of sudo rights.

I've done some research and found that using Supervisor is a common solution for managing queue workers, but it typically requires sudo access to set up. Since shared hosting environments don't grant sudo rights, I'm stuck.

Has anyone successfully tackled a similar issue or found an alternative approach to schedule Laravel queue jobs on shared hosting without needing sudo access? Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you ask the maintainer of the shared hosting to run the commands for you?

Comment: can you plz tell us which shared hosting you are using? because services provider has different limitations and are you able to use ssh/terminal provided by hosting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm seeking guidance on how to execute job queues on a shared hosting server environment. Specifically, I'd like to set up and run job queues in a manner suitable for shared hosting infrastructure

Answer (score -2):

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to schedule Laravel queue jobs on shared hosting without sudo rights:

1- SSH Access: Get SSH Access.
2- Cron Job: use this command to run queue job

```
crontab -e
```